# Can't inherit table attribute from parent

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua, lua-table

```
Sprite = {x = 0, y = 0, pos = {z=0}}
function Sprite:new()
    o = {}
    setmetatable(o,self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
s1 = Sprite:new()
s2 = Sprite:new()

s1.x = 10
s1.pos.z = 5

print("s1.x", s1.x, "s2.x", s2.x, "s1.z",s1.pos.z, "s2.z", s2.pos.z )

s2.x = 20
s2.pos.z = 50

print("s1.x", s1.x, "s2.x", s2.x, "s1.z",s1.pos.z, "s2.z", s2.pos.z )
```

In the above code snippet, I define a class `Sprite` which has `x(int),y(int),pos(table)` 3 attributes, but when I init two object `s1,s2`. I found that they shared the `pos` attribute.

If you run the code, it will print:

```
s1.x    10  s2.x    0   s1.z    5   s2.z    5
s1.x    10  s2.x    20  s1.z    50  s2.z    50
```

`s1` and `s2` has their own `x,y` attribute, but share `pos` attribute, if `s1.pos.z` is changed, so as the `s2.pos.z`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lua shares tables(keeps them as reference), and copy variables. Use metatables for methods, and keep fields copying them in your object table.

```
Sprite = {
  instanceData = { x = 0, y = 0, pos = {z = 0} },
  method = function(self) print("do smth with "..self) end
}

function Sprite:new()
  local o = deepCopy(self.instanceData)
  setmetatable(o,self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

deep copy implementation can be found [wiki/CopyTable](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable)

Comment: But if you copy all data from the class, what purpose will `__index` serve? It will never be called.

Comment: @lhf I copy only field values(instanceData). There is no need to copy methods, so metatable is better for them. It will be more clear solution, to create class table, but its a simple example. Maybe I'll provide it later.

Comment: (at)Seagull @lhf Thax for your quick reply, It seems lua only copy attribute on write. So the table(reference?) was shared.

Comment: @user964860 Also look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming There is a lot lua OOP implementations, and if you want an quick and reliable result, consider to use one of them. For learning purposes, there are also some material there.

Answer (score 3):

In `Sprite:new`, the variable `self` always has `Sprite` as its value. So, `self.pos` refers to `Sprite.pos`. Try changing to `o.pos={}`. Also, consider making `o` a local.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite represents the class, hence you can think of Sprite table as the "class wide" entries: they will be shared by all "instances". Instance specific entries should be in the o table:

```
Sprite = {classX = 0, classY = 0} -- class; vars shared by all instances
function Sprite:new()
    o = {pos = {z=0}}
    setmetatable(o,self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

Note that "shared" really does mean shared at the reference level, so all instances will see the same values and any changes made by one instance will be seen by all others. OTOH data you put in o table is per instance. Putting this in Sprite.new() ensures that all instances have the same fields, but their own data; changes by one instance will not affect any other instance.

That said, your Sprite:new() does not define self.__newindex. So Sprite.classX = 5 will be seen by all instances, as expected, but s1.classX = 6 will only be seen by s1: it will create a new field, thus hiding that of Sprite. From then on, changes to Sprite.classX will no longer be seen by s1 (but will be by all other instances that have not overridden Sprite.classX). To get around that, you could do this:

```
function Sprite:new()
    o = {pos = {z=0}}
    setmetatable(o,self)
    self.__index = self
    self.__newindex = self
    return o
end
```

In Lua console you would see this if you played around with this:

```
> s1=Sprite:new()
> s2=Sprite:new()
> print(s1.classX, s2.classX)
0       0
> Sprite.classX=1
> print(s1.classX, s2.classX)
1       1
> s1.classX=3
> print(s1.classX, s2.classX)
3       3
```

Without that change, that last output will show "3   1" and changes to Sprite.classX would not be visible in s1.